# How to generate unique values in an array in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, validation

Salutations,

I'm writing a function that generates an array of random values between 1 and 49 for a lottery game. Assigning the random values to each slots in the array is easy enough (already wrote a functioning value generator), as is sorting the values in the array, but then I have to validate that they're all unique.

Thanks in advance for any help, either directly here or by pointing me in the good direction. (Didn't find exactly what I was looking for with the prompted suggestions.)

```
    void generateLottery(short lottery[], const short LENGTH, const short MIN, const short MAX) {
    for (short i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
        short counter = 0;
        lottery[i] = generateRandomValue(MIN, MAX);
        while (lottery[counter] != NULL) {
            if (lottery[i] == lottery[counter]) {
                lottery[i] = generateRandomValue(MIN, MAX);
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
    sortLottery(lottery, LENGTH);
}
```

Comment: You need to [shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) some simply generated array with unique values.

Comment: Take a look at [the example code for std::iota.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be an array? Instead you could use an [unordered set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/) which only accepts unique values.

Comment: @emsimpson92 It does. /cry
This is for an algorithm and basic programming class, and it's an exercise with arrays.

Comment: @EugeneSh. This does provide me wiith an actual algorithm, so I guess I'll work with that. Kind of having a brain fart at the moment, but I thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @user4581301 That technique looks swell, but unfortunately I can't use that as it defies the pupose of the exercise, which is to practice algorithm and, I guess, reasoning like a programmer. Nice cookie-cutter though!

Comment: This isn't exactly on the topic of the question, but I'd recommend revisiting the logic in your inner loop (where you check if `lottery[counter] != NULL`. `NULL` is just a macro alias of 0 with is idiomatically used exclusively with pointers (and, from C++11 onwards, is often avoided in favor of `nullptr`). In addition to idiomatic preferences, though (which ultimately aren't a strong reason to do anything anyway), there are some potential correctness concerns: what if `lottery` is passed to your function already containing non-zero values?

Comment: You could throw your random number generation inside a while loop, with the condition being `find(array.begin(), array.end(), randomnum)`

Comment: That way if it finds the number in the array it just generates a new one.

Comment: Another method is to choose randomly form an array filled with the numbers 1-49, then swap the selected value with the last, then choose randomly from 1-48, and so on...

Comment: You can adapt that method so that you only have to store the selected numbers; then you can use it to choose e.g. numbers from 1 to a million without having to first create an array that holds a million numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
    lottery[i] = generateRandomValue(MIN, MAX);
    while (lottery[counter] != NULL) {
        if (lottery[i] == lottery[counter]) {
            lottery[i] = generateRandomValue(MIN, MAX);
        }
        counter++;
```

you can just use `std::find` to generate a new number if the number is found. Something like this...

```
    do
    {
      lottery[i] = generateRandomValue(MIN, MAX);
    }while(std::find(lottery.begin(), lottery.end(), lottery[i]));
    counter++;
```

As others have mentioned, this is not the most efficient method, so it all depends on how many entries you expect to have.

Comment: Good luck with the worst-case time complexity :-)

Comment: They just asked for a solution involving arrays. Nothing in the post says that it has to be microsoft level efficient.

Comment: You can do better than this. Just because it doesn't have to be "Microsoft-level efficient" doesn't mean that you shouldn't at least strive for Fisher-Price level efficiency. There are known, simple algorithms for this type of thing that don't need an unbounded number of O(n) traversals.

Comment: Fair enough. Regardless, until someone provides a better answer, I'll leave mine up.

Comment: If this is for a class assignment, this solution will lead to the inevitable question "what happens if the random generator keeps picking the same number?". The OP should prepare an answer for that, I guess.

Comment: Microsoft level efficient?  Usually takes them 4 to 6 versions before the thing's worth using.

Comment: Haha guys, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of 49 integers, numbered from 1 to 49. Shuffle array. Pick first `n` elements. You now have `n` unique random numbers in the range 1,49.

Simple Shuffling:

1. Start at index 0.
2. Generate random number % 49.
3. Swap arr[index] with arr[randomnumber].
4. repeat with index 1,2,3,4...48.

Comment: Right way to do this and discussed already in the comments. The problem is shuffle how? The usual `<algorithm>` tricks are denied to them.

Comment: @user4581301 Ah, I wasn't aware they needed help just `shuffling` the array. I was giving advice on how to have a constant time operation instead of attempting to check each time if the values are unique or not.